# Path to shorcut is different on Windows 10 and Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows, process, path

In my application I use Process.Start to start a .exe that has a shortcut on my desktop.

Like this:

```
 process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\PCName\Desktop\MyAppName - Snelkoppeling"
 process.Start();
```

Ok this works perfect on my device (Windows 10 Pro), it starts MyAppName - Snelkoppeling..

But when I use my application on another device (Windows Pro 7) it wont start the process, but the location to the shortcut is the same only the name of the device is different ofcours.

I keep getting a could not find file exception..

Any ideas?

Comment: sure its not `c:\users\username\desktop`? - use `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), @"MyAppName - Snelkoppeling.EXE")` to be sure.

Comment: @AlexK. Hey I did it like you said, but still it gives me that error..

Answer (score 0):

Alex said right, the path should be accessed dynamically

Also make sure the username of the user on Windows 7 is normal text (without spaces and other special characters). Windows 10 is much more powerful in this case.

Hope, I helped.